# Can I get this reopened "Bias in the workplace against white males"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

[How can I avoid discrimination against me as a member of a non-protected class](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/96978/3192)

This was obviously closed for the subject matter and not for any lack of addressable goal, as evidenced by the comments.

update: I have taken Dukeling's advice and edited the title, which seems to have helped.

Any further edits or suggestions would be most welcome.

Comment: I have already cast a reopen vote. I find it extremely strange that the question "requires a goal we can address" when the goal has been clearly specified in bold.

Comment: @MaskedMan The close votes, I think, proved the very point they were denying.

Comment: Down voter:  Care to explain?

Comment: Apparently, "I don't want to talk about this issue" = "Question doesn't have a goal we can address" ;-)

Comment: @MaskedMan I took great pains to make sure that the question would specifically be structured correctly and meet the criteria for a good question. i think your assessment was correct.  I'm not surprised at who did the VTC.

Comment: There is no addressable goal because your situation is focused around your perception of bias against you as a white male, but nothing has actually happened to you to propose a response to. If you had been fired/made redundant and your only explanation was due to your gender/race, then the question would be answerable. But at the moment it's not, thus the close votes. I would move on.

Comment: FWIW, "How can I avoid discrimination against me as a member of a non-protected class" might be a less controversial title and more generally applicable.

Comment: @Dukeling good idea

Comment: I cast a close vote because the question was a hypothetical with no country, business, or event specified. This was made known at the start of the question and no attempt was made by the asker to address this.

Comment: In the days leading up to Richard asking this question, we had a number of questions (from one member) asking pretty much the same question - he had each of his attempts downvoted/VTC'd/Deleted.  Then Richard asked this question.  I imagine that any DV/VTC comes from people with "majority discrimination" fatigue.

Comment: @Dukeling thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Is this partially a legal question?

  Probably.
- Is the non-legal answer roughly just "be a good employee" (and, more generally "do whatever you'd *normally* do to get ahead or protect your job in the business world")?

  It seems so.

I don't really have a problem with the subject matter of the question, I just fail to see a non-trivial answer to the question (that also wouldn't just be listing what "a good employee" looks like, which, as an answer to that question, or any question really, just seems ... wrong).

Is that a good enough reason to close the question? I think so, yes.

---

I honestly think that people closed the question because they don't think white people are being discriminated against, and people reopened it because they think there is discrimination, but no-one's really considering whether the question's actually answerable.

The answers so far, in my mind, 100% supports this - they largely come down to "be a good employee" (and briefly touch on disclosing and coping with disabilities, which would make good questions, but that isn't what was asked here).

Comment: It breaks down to this.  I don't want to be disadvantaged because of one status or protected because of others.  Or, in other words, I don't want to use the same tactics to protect myself that others would use to discriminate against me.  I don't see that as trivial

Comment: @RichardU If you believe people will discriminate based on one status, you can try to counter-balance that by using another status, or you can just accept they will do that and go above and beyond in your career - that may not be a trivial or "fun" choice, but I'm not sure its one we can really help you make. The most you can do is not willingly reveal your status (if you focused on how to do that specifically, I'd have been inclined to say the question is okay).

Comment: Thank you for your input.  It has been very useful.

Comment: Frankly I think "what does a good employee act like" is a great topic that is needed.  I agree that is overly broad and it needs to be drilled down from there, but general discrimination is part of every workplace and does come in all forms from shoes and hair style to skin color and religion.  I think the original question is over broad as there would need to be specifics to the type of white discrimination.  As most discrimination questions they lack the specifics to what makes them "feel" discriminated on instead of just stating "I am being discriminated against.

Comment: @mutt I mean "be a good employee" in the more general sense, not in a way that's specific to the situation, as in do your job well, play the politics game and improve yourself. Such a response wouldn't be specific to the asker's discrimination (or even specific to dealing with discrimination in general) - it's purely a way to increase your value. Any given disability (which is not really what that question is about) might have some specific "how to cope with this in the workplace" answers, but the actual discrimination does not (at least not that I can see).

Comment: @Dukeling I agree it needs some defining specific which gives it credence to an answer and not some generic mantra to work by.  I think this question has a basis, but doesn't have the specific defining part to promote a healthy answer...